# TeeChart showing abnormal message box and accumulating memory

Tags: teechart

I am using TeeChart Pro v2013.0.1.4.131120 32bit ActiveX in an MFC application. There are 15 chart windows dynamically created on a dialog running on a UI thread and all of the charts windows get constantly updated by messages from the main thread. I am encountering the following issues:

1. An abnormal message box with "2." written inside constantly pops up once after the chart windows are created and updated.
2. Although at regular interval I am freeing the data for each chart with the following code I find that memory is continuously getting accumulated.

This is the code I'm using:

```
long sz = pchart_->GetSeriesCount();    
for (int i = 0; i <= sz; ++i) {
   pchart_->Series(i).Clear(); 
}
pchart_->RemoveAllSeries();
```

Can anyone please help/ highlight me regarding what is going wrong here?

Comment: Could you please add an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so we can reproduce the problem at our side?

Comment: Please help where to attach the demo application.

Comment: You can use [Steema Upload Page](http://steema.net/upload/)

Comment: Sorry, but I find the link you provided (http://steema.net/upload/) broken. Please provide a valid link.

Comment: Ok, finally could add SampleChart.zip to steema.net/upload. Please check.

Comment: StAnalizerDlg.cpp has more than 17k lines of code! Please, arrange a simple example so we can easily investigate where the problem is.